# How to set myheading equal to leader's heading in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

what i'm trying to do is:

Pseudo code

```
to flock
 check flockmates
 if find any leader inside the flockmates
   change myheading to leader's heading
 else
   follow flocking rule [separate, allign, cohesion]
 end
```

Below is code that I use.

```
turtles-own
[ flockmates
  nearest-neighbor
  leader?
  leader
 ]

to setup
__clear-all-and-reset-ticks

ask n-of population patches with [ pcolor = blue]
 [sprout 1
  [set color white
   set size 0.6
   set leader? false]
  ]
choose-leaders
end

to choose-leaders
ask n-of ((percent_of_leader / 100) * population ) turtles
[set leader? true
set color black
set size 0.6
set leader self
]
end

to go
 ask turtles [flock]
end

to flock
 find-flockmates
 let nearby-leaders turtles with [leader? ]
 ifelse any?  nearby-leaders
 [ set heading [heading] of nearby-leaders]

 [ find-nearest-neighbor
  ifelse distance nearest-neighbor < minimum-separation
    [separate]
    [ if any? flockmates
      [align
      cohere ]]]
end

to find-flockmates  ;; turtle procedure
 set flockmates other turtles in-cone vision vision-angle
end

to find-nearest-neighbor ;; turtle procedure
 set nearest-neighbor min-one-of flockmates [distance myself]
end
```

however when I run the code, this error message pop-up **can't set turtles variable HEADING to non-number [147].** and it point to this code [set heading [heading] of nearby-leaders]. what did i do wrong here? really appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because nearby-leaders in your code is a turtle-set, you should use `one-of`:

```
set heading [heading] of one-of nearby-leaders
```